# How can I skip all target except Android for Multiplatform Kotlin library publication to maven?

Tags: android, maven, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I’m using `maven-publish` to publish my multiplatform library to `maven` repo. My publishing config looks like:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
                groupId = projectGroup
                artifactId = projectArtifactName
                version = "${android.defaultConfig.versionName}"
                tasks.getByName("bundle${buildType.capitalize()}Aar").outputs.files.forEach {
                    artifact(it)
                }
            }
        }
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
        }
    }
}
```

As a result of publishing i get several modules:

```
└── repository
    └── com
        └── example
            ├── lib-ios
            │   ├── 1.0.0
            ├── lib-iossim
            │   ├── 1.0.0
            ├── lib-macos
            │   ├── 1.0.0
            ├── lib-metadata
            │   ├── 1.0.0
            └── lib
                ├── 1.0.0
```

After that i use this library in Android app as:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.example:lib:1.0.0")
}
```

So it looks like i need to publish to `maven` only Android part of my library, since i use `carthage` to publish iOS part.

How can I skip all target except Android for Multiplatform Kotlin library publication to maven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your grade > lib > publishing tasks. There should be:

1. `Publish[module_name]PublicationToMavenLocal` and
2. `Publish[module_name]PublicationToMavenRepository`

This should publish only Android part of the library.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me! Just wanted to clarify that i have tasks named as `publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal ` and `publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository`

It looks like i have `Maven` instead of `Android` in task name because of name of publication - `create<MavenPublication>("maven") `

Comment: Answer updated to reflect different module names. Thanks for the heads up.